# Tried accesing my custom shared object, but permission is denied

Tags: linux, chmod, libraries, c++

Created a basic C++ shared objects file using g++:

```
// calculate.hpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

  // typedef struct ...;
  // function decls
  int Add(int x, int y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

with a C++ file that implements the functions:

```
// calculate.cpp    
#include <iostream>
#include "calculate.hpp"
    
int Add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y; 
}
```

and I basically created the shared library via

```
g++ -fPIC -shared calculate.cpp -o calculate.so
```

My C# app on my Linux system can run it flawlessly:

```
// sandbox.cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace sandbox;

class Program
{
    // (changed the directory due to privacy stuff)
    [DllImport("/.../shared-objects/calculate/libcalculate.so")]
    static extern int Add(int x, int y);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = Add(15, 20);
        Console.WriteLine($"Result of so is: {result}");
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run it via a Tizen application package (a C# app for the TV) through my Smart TV, this is what I get:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library '/home/guest/libtest/libcalculate.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: /home/guest/libtest/libcalculate.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

As you can see, I have the .so file in /home/guest/, but I also tested it in other places: /lib/, /opt/data, /home/. Just anywhere I can think of. Still the same exception: permission denied.

I modified the file through chmod too (currently -rwxrwxrwx) and made sure my ls -ld of / /usr and /usr/lib was all good, and still permission denied. Now the question is whether this actually is an access-related issue, or more to do with how app packages are handled on a TV?